# How to create/update/view two modal class with one serializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model class. I want to create/update/view both model class with one serializer. I have tried but its not working.

Here is my modal class:

```
class PackageQuantity(models.Model):
    comp_code = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.SensorDevice',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class PackageComponent(models.Model):
    pkg_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    package = models.ForeignKey(
        'PackageQuantity',
        on_delete= models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer class

```
class PackageQuantity(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = oss.PackageQuantity
        fields = ['comp_code', 'quantity',]

class PackageComponentSerializer1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = PackageQuantity()
    class Meta:
        model = oss.PackageComponent
        fields = ['pkg_code','package']
```

Views.py

```
class PackageComponent1ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.PackageComponentSerializer1
    queryset = oss.PackageComponent.objects.all()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: also include the code that you tried with and what are the problems you're facing.

Comment: @VishalSingh I have added my serializer class

Comment: add your views.

Comment: @VishalSingh I have added the views.py class too. I know I need to override here create, update and delete method but not sure how to do it. Please help me out it will be of great help

Comment: One way is to override the `create` method on your `PackageComponentSerializer`. The documentation actually has an excellent example of something like this.  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers